# Setting up network of linux servers for multiple user access

Tags: linux, networking, users

looking for a good/best practice soln for dealing with multiple users, accessing multiple linux servers within a network... the users will be accessing the network remotely, tunneling behind the firewall..

the assumption is that a given server might be the physical server with each user's home/working dir. the idea is to allow users who need access, to be able to login/access the dirs/apps on other boxes as required. but there's no need to have a separate user/passwd for each box. so what's a good/best approach to accomplish this?

thoughts/comments appreciated..

thanks

Comment: What's your linux distribution ?

Answer (score 2):

I've asked the same question some days ago:

[Centralize authentication and user's home folder](https://serverfault.com/questions/111351/centralize-authentication-and-users-home-folder)

Response :

> Most common solutions are NIS+NFS or LDAP+NFS. NIS is easier to set up than LDAP, but LDAP supports multiple OSes and is more flexible in that sense. I would recommend using one of these two since both are well documented and established in the industry.

I've installed NIS+NFS, so far it was an easy setup. I have 1 server sharing users home folder with nfs and authenticate users with nis for the others servers !

Comment: I would suggest taking the time to do an LDAP deployment. NIS isn't terrible, but having worked with both (NIS for longer than I care to admit) I much prefer the LDAP-backed solution

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole bunch of ways to do this.  Probably the most popular, modern way is using [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_%28protocol%29) and [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules).  The "old standy" is [NIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service).  Some people might point you at OpenLDAP, but keep in mind that LDAP is a directory service, not an authentication service.  Attempts to "authenticate off of LDAP" are hacks normally used to shoehorn Linux into an existing Active Directory network.

Comment: Kerberos is pretty nice, but in my experience it's a pain to set up (it may have gotten easier in the last 3 or so years though, and worth considering even if it hasn't).  In defense of LDAP: `/etc/passwd` is nothing more than a directory of users, and I don't find it's PAM/NSS integration any clunkier than Kerberos :)